# Post some value in HTML to a PHP?

Tags: php, post

How can I post some value in HTML to a PHP?

Here is my situation :

1. in **`Download.php`**, i am going to Export a Excel in csv format.
2. the data to Export are from a editable table, let say in **`myTable.php`**.
   and those data I am not going to store them in the data Base, I just want to let the user download a Excel version of their edit.

I can put my data into javascript, and use ajax to post a form, 
but if then, I don't know how to handle the result to make it work.
as "Download.php"  is create the file by setting the header like

```
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');
```

and that is not working in a ajax call feed back.

**if I am not using Ajax, how can I put data like `$('#mainTable').html()` into a hidden input or something ?**

Answer (score 2):

If you are rendering your results as a download (for example a spreadsheet), then don't use ajax.

The header() function asks the browser to act in a certain manner, in this case render the requested page as a download. In the case of unit, you forgo this, as you take control of output.

Therefore, a plain

```
<form ...action="Dowload.php">
...
</form>
```

will suffice.

Comment: how can I put data like $('#mainTable').html() into a hidden input or something ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download file directly using ajax. If you want to make a download work using `Ajax` you can return download url in response and apply it like `document.location = "your_download_url"` to start download process.

**EG**

```
someObject.click(function(){
       $.ajax({...,
       success:function(download_url_from_server){
           document.location = download_url_from_server;
           //eg of download url: http://yoursite.com/download.php?file=yourfile
       }});           
    })
```

Comment: my data didn't store in database, and i don't think passing the data at the url is a good idea.